# Problem to save picture to mediaLibrary with expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise, expo

i'm completly new to react and react native too, but i'm trying to learn it.

I'm having a problem when i try to save picture to my phone gallery

So, i'm importing

```
import { MediaLibrary } from 'expo-media-library'
```

also i'm usigng states

```
const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
const [type, setType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.back);
const [cameraRef, setCameraRef] = useState(null)
```

and here all works fine except saving the photo

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{alignSelf: 'center'}} onPress={async() => {
            if(cameraRef){
              let photo = await cameraRef.takePictureAsync();
              console.log('photo', photo);
              MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync(photo.uri)

            }
          }}>
```

in my console log i see the object

```
    photo Object {
     "height": 4156,
     "uri": "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B7CCEDB6-DFC5-4898-BD70-B2FF1159FC1B/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Ftest-5bfa90d8-12e9-44fe-a19d-69bb5eeb74b9/Camera/D783C734-29B9-489B-9798-A0737388E93C.jpg",
     "width": 2376,
}
```

But i'm not able to find a way to save it to camera roll, i'm always getting this error

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expoMediaLibrary.MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync')]
```

Any help would be appreciate

R.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're getting undefined object error with promise since you did not also concerned `MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync()` with `await`.

You should maybe put `MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync()` with `await` too just like you did on takePictureAsync() since it is a async function.

```
let photo = await cameraRef.takePictureAsync();
console.log('photo', photo);
await MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync(photo.uri);
```

Just an assumption, hope it will help you to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening due to import issue.

```
// Change from this
import { MediaLibrary } from 'expo-media-library';
// To this
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';
```

This was answered in below thread. Mentioning here because if someone may come across this issue again.

[[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expoMediaLibrary.MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync')]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63532277/unhandled-promise-rejection-typeerror-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating)